# CGAffineTransform gives expected expression error

Tags: ios, objective-c

IU am experienced in Java, but new to Objective C, so this might be very stupid. Nevertheless, I have been struggling for a while now, searching for the reason why I get an expected expression error from the following code.

```
CGAffineTransform move = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(middleX, middleY);
[shapePath applyTransform:move];
[shapePath stroke];
[shapePath fill];
```

shapePath is a UIBezierPath, middleX and middleY are CFFloats.

The error is a "parse issue", it just says "expected expression", on the first line above

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you could share the error you are getting

Comment: It is a parse error, just says "expected expression" (as mentioned in the question)

Comment: I am assuming that you have defined two variables called `middleX` and `middleY` above that code but just excluded them from the question, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit

With the extra context that you were using this inside a `switch` statement I know what is wrong.

You can't declare variables inside a switch statement without enclosing the cases in curly brackets. You can read about why this is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5163657/608157) (in short, they don't introduce new scopes).

For example, creating a variable like this gives the compiler error that you are facing:

[image]

but if you add braces around the case (like below) then you can create variables within that scope

[image]

---

## Original answer

There is no problem with the code that you have shown in that question. The following code works for me without any compiler errors:

```
UIBezierPath *shapePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
CGFloat middleX = 10.0;
CGFloat middleY = 10.0;

CGAffineTransform move = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(middleX, middleY);
[shapePath applyTransform:move];
[shapePath stroke];
[shapePath fill];
```

You should look for other syntax errors in the just above what you have included in your question.

For example, as [suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14168319/608157), you may be missing a closing bracket (`}`) somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work. See my answer below... 2 hours spent on this :( Tack så mycket för hjälpen ändå David. Hoppas du får en bra dag!

Answer (score 0):

This code was in a switch clause. When I declared the move variable outside it, it disappeared. Don't know why though. Now it works.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163617/expected-expression-before-in-switch-statement about declaring variables in switch/case. Perhaps that was your problem?

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Thanks, now I know!